# How can I execute a function stored as a dictionary value with specific arguments?

Tags: python, dictionary, switch-statement

I'm trying to implement a custom switch-case in Python using dictionaries to handle player input for a text-based game. My idea is to map player input to a corresponding function, which is simple in theory, looking something like this:

```
def foo():
    print("foo")

def bar():
    print("bar")

dic = {"foo":foo, "bar":bar}

action = input("> ")
function = dic.get(action)
function()
```

outputs what you'd expect the corresponding function to, i.e. "foo" from function foo with input "foo".

However, in practice the trouble arises when I need to pass specific arguments per function. When adding parenthesis to a function within the dictionary to specify arguments, as you all know, executes the function instead of storing it, i.e. modifying the above code to

```
def foo():
    print("foo")

def bar():
    print("bar")


action = input("> ")

dic = {"foo":foo(),"bar":bar()}

function = dic.get(action)
function()
```

executes both `foo()` and `bar()` regardless of input.

My current function looks as follows:

```
def get_action(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    # -----INPUT-----
    action = input("> ").lower()

    possible_actions = {
        "foo":foo(arg1),
        "bar":bar(arg2),
        "foobar":foobar(arg2, arg3)
        }

    # execute function that corresponds to the action from the switch case
    action_to_execute = possible_actions.get(action)
    action_to_execute()
```

How can I change this so that I can store the functions properly and input arguments as needed?

Comment: Where would `arg1`, `arg2` and `arg3` come from?

Comment: @SergeyA Those represent the arguments to be passed, i.e. possible exits for rooms or inventories for functions that need them.

Comment: My question was would they be known at the time of creation of those functions (so that `partial` or `lambda` solution would work) or will they only become known when they are actually invoked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Possible way to store values as arguments and access them when needed.

## I borrowed code from the original question.

```
def foo(a):
    print("foo")

def bar(a):
    print("bar")

def foobar(a, b):
    print('foobar')


def get_action(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    # -----INPUT-----
    action = input("> ").lower()

    possible_actions = {
        "foo": (foo, arg1),
        "bar": (bar, arg2),
        "foobar": (foobar, (arg2, arg3))
        }

    # execute function that corresponds to the action from the switch case
    # Make sure you are checking for errors first!
    if not possible_actions.get(action, None):
        return None

    func = possible_actions.get(action)[0]
    args = possible_actions.get(action)[1]
    if len(args) > 1:
        func(*args)
    else:
        func(args)
```

Answer (score 2):

[`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial)ly apply the functions first:

```
from functools import partial

possible_actions = {
    "foo": partial(foo, arg1),
    "bar": partial(bar, arg2),
    "foobar": partial(foobar, arg2, arg3)
}
```

Partial application allows you to give arguments to a function without calling the function.

You could also wrap the calls in a `lambda` to achieve the same, but `partial` avoids some problems that that can cause.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store a zero-argument function that *calls*, for example, `foo` with the desired  argument.

```
possible_actions = {
    "foo": lambda: foo(arg1),
    "bar": lambda: bar(arg2),
    "foobar": lambda: foobar(arg2, arg3)
}
```

Or alternatively, use `functors.partial`:

```
from functools import partial

possible_actions = {
    "foo": partial(foo, arg1),
    "bar": partial(bar, arg2),
    "foobar": partial(foobar, arg2, arg3)
}
```

The difference between the two is that the `lambda` treats `arg1` as a free variable; its value when the function is *called* is used, not its value when the function is *defined*. `partial` "freezes" the value used when `partial` is called. (This can be simulated with `lambda`, somewhat verbosely, with `lambda x=arg1: foo(x)`.)